# Двусторонняя синхронизация input и slider ui

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui

Есть ползунок ui, который вставляет свои значения в 2 инпута.
Нужно сделать связь двустороннюю, т.е. при изменении инпутов должно изменяться положение ползунка относительно новому значению. Нужно как-то создать функцию где это все будет обрабатываться, а потом это прикрутить к событию onchange().

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <title></title>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $( function() {
       $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
       range: true,
       min: 100,
       max: 100000,
       step: 20,
       values: [ 100, 100000 ],
       slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount_before" ).val( ui.values[ 0 ]);
             $( "#amount_after" ).val( ui.values[ 1 ])  // "Это берутся значения скролла, отдельно левого, отдельно правого"           
       }
      });   
         $('#amount_before').val( $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ));
    $('#amount_after').val( $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ));// "Это встраиваются значения инпута"
    
       } );
 </script>
     
</head>

<body>
<input name="price_from" id="amount_before" size="6" type="text" onchange="" > <!-- Вот тут при изменении значения в инпуте должно изменяться положение ползунка -->
<br>
 <input name="price_to"  size="6" id="amount_after" onchange= "ch()"  type="text" >
 <div id="slider-range" style="margin-top:10px; width:400px;" ></div><!-- Тут аналогично -->
       <br/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Что у вас не получилось?

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev Не получилось сделать так, чтобы при изменении значения в поле инпута, менялось положение ползунка.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$("#slider-range").slider({
  range: true,
  min: 100,
  max: 100000,
  step: 20,
  values: [100, 100000],
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    $("#amount_before").val(ui.values[0]);
    $("#amount_after").val(ui.values[1])
  }
});

$('#amount_before').val($("#slider-range").slider("values", 0))
$('#amount_after').val($("#slider-range").slider("values", 1))

$('#amount_before').change(function() {
  $("#slider-range").slider('values', 0, $(this).val());
});

$('#amount_after').change(function() {
  $("#slider-range").slider('values', 1, $(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input name="price_from" id="amount_before" size="6" type="text">
<br>
<input name="price_to" size="6" id="amount_after" type="text">

<div id="slider-range" style="margin-top:10px; width:400px;"></div>
```